# discory.py BeautifulSoup get a class behind many div classes

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, discord, bots, discord.py

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="one">
   <div class="two">
      <div class="three">
         <a class="three" href="link">My link</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can i get the href link?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all links in the html page.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(f"Found the URL:{a['href']}")
```